# Printing the current date/time with sub-second precision

Tags: osx, bsd

GNU `date(1)` understands the `%N` format spec, which outputs nanoseconds, so:

```
$ date +%H:%M:%S.%N
```

outputs 19:10:03.725196000

BSD date doesn't understand %N. How can I print the current time with sub-second precision on OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a modern-enough Perl interpreter handy (`Time::HiRes` is bundled since 5.7.2), you could use some variation of this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);
use POSIX       qw(strftime);

my ($s,$us) = gettimeofday();
printf "%s.%06d\n", strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime($s)), $us;
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./t.pl 
19:52:35.408520
```

If you don't have perl (or don't want to use it), but you do have a C compiler, you could use this:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct timeval now;
    struct tm *tmp;
    char timestr[9];
    int rc;

    rc = gettimeofday(&now, 0);
    if (rc != 0) {
        perror("gettimeofday");
        return 1;
    }

    tmp = localtime(&now.tv_sec);
    if (tmp == 0) {
        perror("localtime");
        return 1;
    }

    rc = strftime(timestr, sizeof(timestr), "%H:%M:%S", tmp);
    if (rc == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "strftime call failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s.%06ld\n", timestr, now.tv_usec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On a side note: (I know very little about Perl)... I was curious about the speed of interpreted Perl vs the c executable... As expected the c executable was much faster to load/run.. (approx 16 times faster, over 100 consecutive itterations)... So, to be fair to Perl, I compiled the Perl script using `pp` (from *libpar-packer-perl*)... To my surprise, this perl executable was 11 times **slower** than the interpreted Perl script (ie, *170* times slower than the c executable)... Is this normal for compiled perl? ..

Comment: `pp` packs the complete perl executable, library and dependencies in a single, compressed archive. If the script is short-lived, loading all that and decompressing is going to have a huge overhead compared to how efficient your OS is about caching frequently used code (and loading only the parts that are actually used). I don't know of a reason why `pp` would run the code faster either once loaded.

Comment: I ended adopting the C version for the least overhead, thank you