# Subtract two time codes

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, ffmpeg

I need to subtract two time codes from each other, I have multiple in an array and the output looks like this:

```
**Input:**
echo ${arr3[0]}
echo ${arr3[1]}

**Output:**    
00:00:22.180 --> 00:00:25.600
00:00:24.070 --> 00:00:27.790
```

In this example the following equation needs to take place `00:00:25.600 - 00:00:22.180 = output into array`and `00:00:27.790 - 00:00:24.070 = output into the same array` It needs to be in the same format so can use it in FFMPEG.

I also need the first timecode of each array entry, so:

```
00:00:22.180 
00:00:24.070
```

in another array so I can use these inputs in ffmpeg as well.

EDIT:

I'll use the data as follows

```
time=$(The first timecode of the array)
duration=$(Timecodes subtracted)

ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss $time -t $duration -async 1 cut.mp4
```

Comment: I think you should spell out a bit more what data is going into what arrays. If you have arr3 with some timestamp/string data, where should the differences go? Into the same array & position, or a new array? Where should the first timecode data go? If you show how you'll use them, you'll get more useful answers.

Comment: The default time utilities exposed in the shell only work with 1 second level granularity. You're going to have to write your own parser/generator from scratch.

Comment: @symcbean `date (GNU coreutils) 8.25` allows nanosecond accuracy.

Comment: @Fiximan: I stand corrected, and I see you can specify the OUPUT format with nanosecond precision, but how do you convert an input string with fractional seconds into a numeric value?

Comment: @symcbean See my answer below - I found no entry in `info` regarding a nanosecond time -> human readable conversion, thus relied on `bash` integer arithmetic and separated treatment of epoch time and fractional seconds. It's dangerous though, as e.g. [discussed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23778/printing-the-current-date-time-with-sub-second-precision) nanoseconds seem to be a GNU-extension not present in BSD-Unices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array arr3 that contains sample data:

```
declare -a arr3=([0]="00:00:22.180 --> 00:00:25.600"
                 [1]="00:00:24.070 --> 00:00:27.790")
```

You could loop through each element in the array, strip out the start time and end time, convert them to fractional seconds, compute the duration, then covert that duration back to hh:mm:ss.sss format for the ffmpeg command.

```
# converts HH:MM:SS.sss to fractional seconds
codes2seconds() (
  local hh=${1%%:*}
  local rest=${1#*:}
  local mm=${rest%%:*}
  local ss=${rest#*:}
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$hh * 60 * 60 + $mm * 60 + $ss")
)

# converts fractional seconds to HH:MM:SS.sss
seconds2codes() (
  local seconds=$1
  local hh=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $seconds / 3600")
  local remainder=$(bc <<< "$seconds % 3600")
  local mm=$(bc <<< "scale=0; $remainder / 60")
  local ss=$(bc <<< "$remainder % 60")
  printf "%02d:%02d:%06.3f" "$hh" "$mm" "$ss"
)

subtracttimes() (
  local t1sec=$(codes2seconds "$1")
  local t2sec=$(codes2seconds "$2")
  printf "%s" $(bc <<< "$t2sec - $t1sec")
)

declare -a arr3=([0]="00:00:22.180 --> 00:00:25.600"
                 [1]="00:00:24.070 --> 00:00:27.790")

for range in "${arr3[@]}"
do
  duration=$(subtracttimes "${range%% -->*}" "${range##*--> }")
  printf "%s\n" "ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss ${range%% -->*} -t $duration -async 1 cut.mp4"
done
```

The `codes2seconds` function expects input in HH:MM:SS.sss format; it strips out the various elements using parameter expansion then passes them to `bc` for the conversion into total number of seconds.

The `seconds2codes` function expects a fractional number of seconds and reverses the conversion, resulting in an HH:MM:SS.sss string.

The `subtracttimes` function converts the two parameters to fractional seconds then asks `bc` for their difference.

The loop at the end goes through each element of arr3; it uses the above functions to calculate the duration (again using parameter expansion to retrieve the two times) then prints out a sample `ffmpeg` call to match your sample output.

Results:

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:22.180 -t 3.420 -async 1 cut.mp4
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:24.070 -t 3.720 -async 1 cut.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for time codes `date` usually pops into my mind. Not the most elegant script, but it does the job...

I assume from your question, that you have beginning and end times already read into respective arrays and will use `start` and `end` as these values here and do it step by step:

```
#!/bin/bash

start=00:00:22.180
end=00:00:24.070

#convert timestamps to epoch time in nano seconds
start_ns="$(date -u -d"$start" +%s%N)"
end_ns="$(date -u -d"$end" +%s%N)"

difference="$(($end_ns-$start_ns))"

#date does not read epoch time in nanoseconds, 
#so it must be converted by division vith 10^9 before display
#date_diff is accurate up to full seconds
#use UTC time (-u) to avoid problems with time zones

date_diff="$( date -u -d@$((difference/1000000000)) +%H:%M:%S )"

#take care of milliseconds as remainder of division by 10^9 and correction by 10^6
ms_diff="$(( $difference%1000000000/1000000 ))"

#combine output to create desired format

echo "$date_diff"."$ms_diff"
```

Result

```
bash script.sh
00:00:01.890
```

All in one line

```
echo "$(date -u -d@"$(( ($(date -u -d"$end" +%s%N) - $(date -u -d"$start" +%s%N))/1000000000 ))" +%H:%M:%S)"."$(( ($(date -u -d"$end" +%s%N) - $(date -u -d"$start" +%s%N))%1000000000/1000000 ))"
```

Please note that I am not aware if nanosecond time in `date` is a POSIX standard feature.